# Force IE8 to use default, IE9 or higher version standards?

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

I am checking my page using IE7 and 8 and it not looks correct as shown in IE9 and IE10.
I have used `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` inside the `<head>`.

How can I force IE8 to make use of IE9 standards or higher or just the default standards?

Comment: "How can I force IE8 to make use of IE9 standards": Download IE9? If IE8 understood and parsed web content as well as IE9 then why wouldn't it in the first place?

Comment: @IanClark I would like not to discuss about how business and products work. Your comment can be replied using only business explanation.

Comment: just FYI: Windows XP/IE8 are officially no longer supported by microsoft as of April 2014, no more security updates or browser updates.  I mention this just so you can make a case to your clients.  As far as making IE8 compatible with IE9+ you have to program to the least common factor, which means you have to forgo the newer web standards.  Maybe also look into an add in like Modernizr